# IBM MQ - AMQ6109: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to start queue manager on windows but getting error as AMQ6109 - An Internal WebSphere MQ has occurred.

```
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'IIB9QMGR' starting.
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.
AMQ6109: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.
```

Verified FDC and I could see below details

```
WebSphere MQ First Failure Symptom Report
Date/Time:- Tue October 17 2017 20:31:24 India Standard Time
UTC Time :- 1508252484.533000
UTC Time Offset   :- 330 (UNKNOWN))
Operating System :- Windows 7 Enterprise x64 Edition, Build 7601:SP1
PIDS :- 724H7220
LVLS :- 7.5.0.1
Product Long Name :- WebSphere MQ for Windows
Vendor :-IBM
Installation Path :- C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
Installation Name :- Installation1    (1)
Probe Id          :- ZC041040
Application Name  :- MQM
Component         :- zcsPipeCreate
SCCS Info         :- F:\build\slot1\p750_P\src\libzc\amqzcsbn.c,
Line Number       :1960
Build Date        :- Mar8 2013
Build Level:-p750-001-130308
Build Type:- IKAP - (Production)
UserID:- spotlapelli
Process Name:- C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\amqzxma0.exe
Addressing mode   :- 32-bit
Process           :- 00007924
Thread            :- 00000001
QueueManager      :- IIB9QMGR
UserApp           :- FALSE
ConnId(1) IPCC    :- 2
ConnId(2) QM      :- 2
ConnId(3) QM-P    :- 2
ConnId(4) App     :- 2
Last HQC          :- 2.0.0-575228
Last HSHMEMB      :- 4.0.0-22980
Major Errorcode   :- STOP
Minor Errorcode   :- OK
Probe Type        :- HALT6109
Probe Severity    :- 1
Probe Description :- AMQ6109: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred
FDCSequenceNumber :- 0

Comment1          :- The filename, directory name, or volume label    syntax is in incorrect 
Comment2          :- \\.\pipe\1\IIB9QMGR\zsocketEC\Zagent
```

---

Performed below steps to resolve but did not worked

1. Restart PC and start queue manager
2. Uninstall and Install MQ

Comment: Can you post the full header of the FDC record (all the lines that begin with `|`, or at least include the Comment1/Comment1 entries towards the bottom.  Is the user you are starting the queue manager as a domain user or a local user?  Is the queue manager configured to run under a Domain account?

Comment: Hi Josh, full header of the FDC record is updated. I am trying to start queue manager as local user. With local user earlier it was working fine

Comment: Is there not any Comment1/Comment2 lines at the end of the lines that start with `|`?  Not for future you can just paste it into the question and then highlight what you want to keep with fixed formatting and click the icon that looks like `{}`.  This will indent what you highlighted by four spaces which will cause it to be left with fixed formatting.

Comment: Here is a link to someone who had a similar problem with v8.0.0.5 last July.  It does not have a resolution but does give some more information on what my be causing it.

Comment: Could you please paste the link

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed pasting the [link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/286972/fails-with-internal-error-when-starting-mq-version.html).  Please also update your question to include the Comment1/Comment2 lines from the FDC file.

Comment: I have verified the FDC and I don't see any lines which include Comment1/Comment2

Comment: Updated with Comment1/Comment2

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited amount of information posted here (no version, platform, other details), its a real challenge (but fortunately I like a challenge...)!

If I've calculated correctly, that probe comes out when a windows queue manager tries to create a named pipe and it fails (Probe 40 from zcsPipeCreate). It is quite rare of that call to fail, and not many causes - the only times it has been seen all turned out to be caused by external influences. A number of times stopping something called SWIFT application services avoided the problem (apparently there's a SWIFT update to it to fix this), although I have no idea what SWIFT Application Services are... If you are not running SWIFT, then you will need to open a PMR with IBM to debug further, although I would recommend updating this question with your full FDC header just in case anything else stands out.

The test program referred to in the link @JoshMc gave is as follows - perhaps try this?

```
#include <windows.h>
main()
{

  HANDLE hnp;
  int rc=0;

   hnp = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\1\\TESTQMGR\\zsocketEC\\Zagent",
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024,1024,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, NULL);

    rc=GetLastError();

    if( hnp == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        printf("CreateNamedPipe failed with %d ",rc );
    else
        printf("NamedPipe created successfully");

}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, Please find the details below                                                           MQ Version: 7.5.0.1, Platform: Windows 7, User Account: Local User

Comment: Nothing in the new information changes my mind - Can you see if you are running a Swift application by any chance, and can you test with it disabled?

Comment: Hi Jason, No Swift application is running on my laptop and no additional softwares installed on my laptop

Comment: Apply 7.5.0.5 or higher and your FDC will change to include a return code and the name trying to be created. Post those 2, and also fill the name into the program above and try compiling and running that standalone. You are heading into (a) PMR territory, but probably (b) reporting to Microsoft territory

Comment: Applied 7.5.0.8  fix pack and updated with comment 1/comment2

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx shows the name listed in the comment is valid. Try using the name "\\\\.\\pipe\\1\\IIB9QMGR\\zsocketEC\\Zagent" in the program in my answer, and see if you get the same error.

Is anything unusual about your windows setup?

Comment: Hi Jason, I have tried executing the above program in Power Shell, C, C++ compiler but I am getting lot of errors

Comment: Sorry, I cut and pasted, missed off the #include... Edited it in place above, and also compiled and ran it locally to confirm that was all. Its a C program, so save it as e.g. test.c, and then just cl test.c

Comment: Thank you Jason for the updated code. I ran the program and this is the output "CreateNamedPipe failed with 161"

Comment: net helpmsg 161
The specified path is invalid.

You'll need to talk to IBM to go any further I'm afraid - I would have said that path is valid, although "The pipename part of the name can include any character other than a backslash" makes me suspicious that perhaps Microsoft somewhere have added validation whereas it runs normally, I dont know, sorry.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I tried by following the steps which provided in [link](https://t-rob.net/2015/06/11/spring-cleaning-a-windows-mq-installation/#more-816) but issue isn't resolved. Now I am trying by applying fix pack 8.0.0.7. I will let u know if this resolves the issue

Comment: One last thought - you havent enabled anything like application verification (gflags / appverifier) have you? Is there *anything* unusual about your windows setup?

Comment: No I haven't enabled anything like application verification. Looks like something went wrong with windows operating system. I have IIB installation on the same desktop and it is running fine without any issues.